# VSCode TypeScript Intellisense not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, typescript2.0

I am pulling my hair out here, literally. VSCode 1.6.0 on Mac, Typescript 2.0.2, but I have also tried 2.0.0.

I've tried targeting es5, es6, with or without commonjs module targeting. I can't get intellisense for other files local to my project nor anything in the node_modules folder. I even installed typescript files from node_modules into my typings folder and those don't work.

The only intellisense I get is for my globally installed typings.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
      ]
}
```

Comment: have also tried 1.8.10 and 2.0.6 which was supposed to fix the node modules problem. And it doesn't

Comment: How are you importing the modules and other files?

Answer (score 5):

After lots of trial and error, I finally got Node, Typescript, VSCode (and Visual Studio for that matter), and IntelliSense working correctly.  This also appears to work with WebStorm.

Create a new Typescript project from the command prompt:

1. `mkdir newproject`  (or any directory name you want)
2. `cd newproject`
3. `npm init -f` (this will create a package.json)
4. `npm install @types/node --save-dev` (this will create a nodes_module folder and a package-lock.json file)
5. Add an initial `tsconfig.json` file.  It could be as simple as `{"files" : ["main.ts"] }`
6. Add an initial empty `main.ts` file to get started

Now launch VS Code point it to open the folder created in the steps above.

**Most important**.  Use the `import` keyword when declaring module use.  Otherwise, IntelliSense flat out won't work.  It took me quite a while a lot of head banging to realize this was the missing step.

Instead of this:

```
var http = require("http");
```

Type this:

```
import http = require("http");
```

And magically, you've got a barebones Typescript + Node project with IntelliSense working.