# What configuration is required to get VSCode working with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get VSCode up and running with TypeScript and am having little success.

I am looking at the following:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript

It looks like once you have installed the compiler VSCode should just work but given the following:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  { 
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "esModuleInterop": true                  
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "blahh",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "tryme",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "ghost",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "tsc-watch",
      "command": "tsc",
      "args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
      "type":"shell",
      "isBackground": true,
      "group":"build",
      "problemMatcher": "$tslint5",
      "presentation":{
        "reveal": "always",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Project**

[image]

**HelloWorld.ts**

```
function sayHello(name: string): void {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}

sayHello(1);
```

Running the build task or tsc from the terminal correctly indicates an error until I change the `1` to a string then generates HelloWorld.js. The editor, however, is not working in that there is no intelliSense, code completion or error highlighting.

I have tried the following but this also has not worked:

[VSCode TypeScript Intellisense not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268442/vscode-typescript-intellisense-not-working)

Other observations:

1. No TypeScript version number shown in the border of the editor (as I see on the example screenshots I see)

[image]

2. When adding the build task following: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode there were no tsc:* templates shown.

**VSCode Info**

```
Version: 1.33.1 (user setup)
Commit: 51b0b28134d51361cf996d2f0a1c698247aeabd8
Date: 2019-04-11T08:27:14.102Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134
```

**Installed Extensions**

*Built In*

```
TypeScript Language Basics: Enabled
... many others
```

*External*

```
code --install-extension alanz.vscode-hie-server
code --install-extension alefragnani.Bookmarks
code --install-extension andyyaldoo.vscode-json
code --install-extension christian-kohler.path-intellisense
code --install-extension daiyy.quick-html-previewer
code --install-extension eamodio.gitlens
code --install-extension Edka.haskutil
code --install-extension esbenp.prettier-vscode
code --install-extension fabiospampinato.vscode-todo-plus
code --install-extension flowtype.flow-for-vscode
code --install-extension gcazaciuc.vscode-flow-ide
code --install-extension hoovercj.haskell-linter
code --install-extension jcanero.hoogle-vscode
code --install-extension justusadam.language-haskell
code --install-extension karigari.chat
code --install-extension mrmlnc.vscode-duplicate
code --install-extension ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin
code --install-extension ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare
code --install-extension ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-audio
code --install-extension ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack
code --install-extension phoityne.phoityne-vscode
code --install-extension SirTobi.code-clip-ring
code --install-extension WakaTime.vscode-wakatime
```

So what I am I missing / should I check for in my setup to enable the interactive VSCode features for TypeScript?

Comment: What does your typescript output look like in the `Output` tab of the built in terminal?

Comment: @DonovanHiland empty when starting project and viewing `HelloWorld.ts`.

When running build task:  

```
> Executing task: tsc -w -p . <


[2:13:24 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[2:13:26 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

Comment: Did you disable the builtin `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` extension? Search `@builtin typescript` the extension view for this. Also, what other extensions do you have installed?

Comment: @MattBierner `TypeScript Language Basics` is enabled will edit question to add extension

Comment: Is `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` enabled too?

Comment: @MattBierner you are right for some reason `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` was disabled (I missed it the first time because I only filtered on `@builtin`). Enabling this fixed the problem. If you want to copy your comment to an answer I'll accept it otherwise will answer myself in a couple of days. Looks like this was disabled due to the flow extension. Enabling `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features`  breaks the the flow extension.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check that the builtin `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` extension is enabled. To do this, search `@builtin typescript` the extensions view.

[image]